# Automatic three digit grouping

Tags: tables, siunitx, grouping

I have huge numbers in tables (some of them are grouped in three digit groups but some are not).

I need to make a small space (or comma) between groups of three digits. 
I have used two packages, `numprint` and `siunitx`, but it doesn't show any changes in my tables.

I know I can do manually using  the backslash but I have heaps of numbers in my tables.

Here my code,

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
x & y & z \\ 
\hline
9,833.823 & 550,245 & 15004568 \\ 
\hline
9,458.230 & 81,345.23 & 198000344 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, do you insert that group separator points manually or is that some input issue? Are you able to insert only decimal points? Which one would you like. Dot or comma?

Answer (score 6):

You should use the package `siunitx` here. But in order to get the tables right, you have to use the `S`-column. I am showing some example below. If you really need left alignment, let me know.

It is not very clear from your post, what the input is, and what output is desired. Speaking of comma and dot. But what ever situation you have, `siuntix` is able to handle that. Just show us, what your input looks like and you output should look like.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%\sisetup{group-separator={,}} % If you prefer... You should add your language as option as well!
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=1.6]S[table-format=3.5]S[table-format=9.0]}
    \toprule
    {x} & {y} & {z} \\ 
    \midrule
    9,833823 & 550,245 & 15004568 \\ 
    9,458230 & 81,34523 & 198000344 \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work for a larger table when you have \hline instead of \toprule

Comment: @Harry Can't imaging that. What does not work? Please be more precise. My solution should be absolutely independent of the choice of table design.

Comment: Can you edit my code using your approach. It doesn't work me. Thanks

Comment: without S-table can we do this?

Comment: I think you may have misinterpreted the meaning of the commas in the inputs: They are probably not decimal markers but, instead, grouping dividers. (At least, that's how they tend to be used in the U.S.) Use the option `input-ignore={,}` as an option for `\sisetup` in order to avoid having to delete the commas by hand from the input.

Comment: @Harry I asked you two times, what the commas and dots are and if you need them. And I still do not know, what the input looks like for your large table. Do you have commas and dots everywhere? Mico's solution should work then, but without your information, I am guessing around and wasting my time.