# Grouping numbers in a table without using S-column

Tags: tables, siunitx, grouping

This is bit different than my [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215490/automatic-three-digit-grouping).

I have a huge tables with 7 to 8 digits.

I need to make a small space between groups of three digits in the numbers. 
I have used the package [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx).

I want to do this without writing `\SI` in front of all the numbers and without using `S`-column in my code as my orginal tables are so big.

Also some of the data in my tables, I got a comma in every three digits so I want to replace this comma with a small space as well.

Here is the simplest version of my code:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
x & y & z \\ 
\hline
9,833.823 & 550,245 & 15004568 \\ 
\hline
9,458.230 & 81,345.23 & 198000344 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image: output]

Comment: The answer to your previous question did not involve putting `\SI` in each cell.

Comment: This seems to be an exact duplicate of the previous question, just asking for a new answer?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Command {S[table-format=1.6]S[table-format=3.5]S[table-format=9.0]} doesn't compile and it gives errors

Comment: Gives us a [minimum (non-)working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to work with.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Sample, the simplest version of the code is given in the problem

Comment: a MWE!!! not just a code snipper.

Comment: You've mentioned repeatedly that your table is "huge" and that the numbers tend to have lots of digits. Is your table simply too large to fit in the text block? If so, you should ask how it might be made smaller.

Comment: As the other comments say, as it stands there is no difference between this question and your earlier one. It is not at all clear what prevents you using an `S` column to do the work. If the problem is performance (it can get slow using `siunitx` with very large tables) then please tighten up the nature of the input and the required output and a 'custom' solution may be forthcoming.

Comment: @Harry you have posted an unusable fragment of code in **two** identical questions and another unusable fragment of code in the comment above, and then say "it gives errors" None of these things are at all useful. Your code examples should be complete from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` They should demonstrate the error, and you should not ask two identical questions.

Answer (score 1):

Your posting seems to contain two separate concerns: (i) some macro-formatting, viz., how to fit a table with many rows and lots of multi-digit numbers into the available text block, and (ii) some micro-formatting, viz., how to group the digits into blocks of three (while disregarding any commas in the input) and how align the numbers on the decimal marker.

For your micro-formatting objectives, by far the best tool around is the `siunitx` package and its `S` column type. It's in your best interest to become familiar with its properties, really. If for some reason you do *not* want to use the `S` column type, you could proceed by (a) replacing all input commas with `\,` (thinspace), (b) inserting `\,` manually wherever needed to achieve grouping in blocks of three, and (c) using lots of `\phantom` statements to achieve alignment on the decimal markers. (The `dcolumn` package lets you avoid taking step (c). However, if you don't wish to use the `S` column type, I can't imagine that you'd want to use the `D` column type either.)

To achieve your macro-formatting objectives, you could start by reducing the amount of intercolumn whitespace and by switching, locally, to a slightly smaller font size. Omitting all vertical lines -- each such line has width `0.4pt` -- is useful both because it economizes on space, i.e., helps with making the table fit inside the available text block, *and* because the table almost certainly looks better and is more readable *without* those vertical lines.

The following screenshot shows that both objectives can be pursued simultaneously.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}  % for good-looking horizontal rules
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{input-ignore={,},
         input-decimal-markers={.},
         group-minimum-digits=4}

\begin{document}

before:

\smallskip
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
x & y & z \\ 
\hline
9,833.823 & 550,245 & 15004568 \\ 
\hline
9,458.230 & 81,345.23 & 198000344 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}


\bigskip
after:

\small  % 11% linear reduction in font size
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % default value: 6pt
\small
\begin{tabular}{@{} S[table-format=4.3]
                    S[table-format=6.2]
                    S[table-format=9.0] @{}}
\toprule
{x} & {y} & {z} \\ 
\midrule
9,833.823 & 550,245 & 15004568 \\ 
9,458.230 & 81,345.23 & 198000344 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```